# Struts1 Hibernate Login page java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: hibernate, struts-1

I am new to Struts and Hibernates. I was given a homework to create a login, register and change password page. I have been able to create the login page but I keep getting a java.lang.ClassCastException. I don't know what I am doing wrong, I have been on this for a while, please help me out. Thank you. Below are my details(sorry about the length):

```
**Login.jsp**
......


<html:form action="login">
     <bean:message key="label.username" />
     <html:text property="userName"></html:text>
     <html:errors property="userName" />
     <br/>
     <bean:message key="label.password"/>
    <html:password property="password"></html:password>
     <html:errors property="password"/>
    <html:submit/>
    <html:reset/>
     </html:form>

      <%
   if(request.getAttribute("msg")!=null){
     %>
        <%= request.getAttribute("msg") %>
          <%} request.setAttribute("msg","null"); %>
         <%
       if(request.getAttribute("msg10")!=null){
         %>
         <%= request.getAttribute("msg10") %>
   <%} request.setAttribute("msg10","null"); %>
    </body>
       </html>

**struts-config.xml**
.....


<form-beans>
       <form-bean name="LoginForm"
        type="com.company.strutsuser.LoginForm" />
     </form-beans> 
     <global-exceptions>
     </global-exceptions>
     <global-forwards></global-forwards>

     <action-mappings>
    <action path="/login" name="LoginForm" validate="true" input="/login.jsp"
        type="com.company.strutsuser.LoginForm">
        <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp" />
        <forward name="failure" path="/login.jsp" />
        <forward name="failure1" path="/ChangePassword.jsp" />
        <forward name="failure2" path="/login.jsp" />

        </action>-->
        </action>
       </action-mappings>
      <message-resources parameter="resource.MessageResource"></message-resources>

.....

**MessageResource.properties**


label.username = Login Detail
      label.password = Password
      label.welcome = Welcome

      error.username =Username is not entered.
      error.password = Password is not entered.

**success.jsp**
.....


<H1>Welcome!</H1>
    <H2>Below are the necessary details</H2>
    <table class="successtable" border="1" cellspacing="10">
    <c:forEach  var="ulogin" items="${ulogin}" varStatus = "varCounter">
    <tr>
    <td>${ulogin.phone_number}</td>
  <td>${ulogin.name}</td>
  </tr>
   </c:forEach>
    </table>
                 <button type="button" onclick="myfunction();">Logout</button><BR />


.....

**LoginForm**


public class LoginForm extends ActionForm{
     private String userName;
          private String password;

            public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

              ActionErrors actionErrors = new ActionErrors();

          if(userName == null || userName.trim().equals("")) {
         actionErrors.add("userName", new ActionMessage("error.username"));
           }
           try {
            if(password == null || password.trim().equals("")) {
             actionErrors.add("password", new ActionMessage("error.password"));
             }
             }catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
          }
        return actionErrors ;
             }

           public String getUserName() {
         return userName;
         }
         public void setUserName(String userName) {
         this.userName = userName;
         }
        public String getPassword() {
         return password;
        }
      public void setPassword(String password) {
         this.password = password;
         }
       public String getName() {
    return name;
       }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }

    public int getPhone_number() {
    return phone_number;
 }

public void setPhone_number(int phone_number) {
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}
private String name;
    private int phone_number;
    public boolean isNew_user() {
    return new_user;
}

public void setNew_user(boolean new_user) {
    this.new_user = new_user;
}
boolean new_user;
private int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

**LoginAction**


 public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction trans = null;
    LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm) form;
         String name = loginForm.getUserName();
         String password =loginForm.getPassword();
         boolean new_user = false;
         LoginForm lform = null;
        String result ="failure";
        try{
            trans = session.beginTransaction();
            List ulogin = session.createQuery("from LoginForm").list();
    for (Iterator iterator = ulogin.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){

                lform = (LoginForm) iterator.next();
if (lform.getUserName().equals(name)&& lform.getPassword().equals(password)&& lform.isNew_user()==new_user){
                    result ="success";
                    break;
                }
     if (lform.getUserName().equals(name)&& lform.getPassword().equals(password)&& lform.isNew_user()!=new_user){
                    result="failure1";
                }
if(lform.getUserName().equals(name)&& !lform.getPassword().equals(password)){
                    result = "failure2";
                    break;
                }
            }


        if(result.equals("success")){
            LoginForm forml = new LoginForm();
            forml.setUserName(lform.getUserName());
            forml.setName(lform.getName());
            forml.setPhone_number(lform.getPhone_number());
            forml.setPassword(lform.getPassword());

            ulogin.add(forml);
            request.setAttribute("ulogin", ulogin);
        }

        if(result.equals("failure")){
    request.setAttribute("msg", "Email and Password Entered are Wrong");
        }
        if(result.equals("failure2")){
            request.setAttribute("msg10", "Password Entered is Wrong");
        }


                                 }
        catch (HibernateException e){
            if (trans!=null)
                trans.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace(); }
         return mapping.findForward(result);

**user.hbm.xml**


<hibernate-mapping>


<class name="com.company.strutsuser.LoginForm" table="user">
       <meta attribute="class-description">
        </meta>
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
      <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
      <property name="userName" column="email" type="string"/>
       <property name="password" column="password" type="string"/>
       <property name="phone_number" column="phone_number" type="string"/>
     <property name="new_user" column="new_user" type="string"/>
 </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>

**Error message the compiler gives**

    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.company.strutsuser.LoginForm cannot be cast to org.apache.struts.action.Action
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason for ClassCastException is that in your struts-config.xml you have mapped `LoginForm` as an Struts Action instead of `LoginAction`.

Modify mapping of your action as

```
<action path="/login" name="LoginForm" validate="true" input="/login.jsp"
        type="com.company.strutsuser.LoginAction">
```

Comment: that seemed to work thank you so much. Although i'm having another error now javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class . What do you think is the problem? Thanks for your help once again

Comment: I solved that problem but now when its about connecting to the success page. It generates the error:                          ERROR: HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.company.strutsuser.LoginForm, setter method of property: phone_number
Aug 05, 2013 8:22:17 PM org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter set
ERROR: HHH000091: Expected type: int, actual value: java.lang.String
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.company.strutsuser.LoginForm.phone_number.

Comment: Is phone_number column type should as string or nvarchar in DB?

Comment: I was able to fix it, I made a mistake in user.hbm.xml. I set my phone_number as string, thank you so much for your help.